# String Remove in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove `-` from a string

```
myString = 12-132-232-1213-3
```

I have already tried

```
 myString.replace('-','');
```

But this would replace only the first charcter `12132-232-1213-3`, but iam expecting `1213223212133` how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify it using the pattern `/-/` with the global modifier `g` as follows:

```
myString.replace(/-/g, '');
// => "1213223212133"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly... whats that `/g` at the end?

Comment: @user3436481 Think of it as saying "match the preceding pattern globally". I'd google "regex g" for the details. [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) is a good resource on regular expressions in general.

Comment: Please try with my answer. This will also help you

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not assigned the value. Try like this and let me know.

myString = myString.replace('/-/g','');

Comment: this will replace only first occurrence.

Comment: now it will. comment was for code before edit. Also, remove quotes before and after regex. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ybL7yz3j/)

Answer (score 0):

There is two methods for remove/replace string in jQuery.

```
var myString = "12-132-232-1213-3";
```

**1** `myString = myString.replace('-','').replace('-','').replace('-','').replace('-','');`

Here you can see `.replace('-','')` is use four times because we want to replace four times `-` in your string.

**2** `myString = myString.replace(/-/g,'');` is more reliable to first one.

**After see both method then most usefull mothod is 2. Because there is no repeated code for replace('-','')**